# How to optimize this algorithm that find all maximal matching in a graph?

Tags: swift, algorithm, optimization, matching

In my app people give grades to each other, out of ten point. Each day, an algorithm computes a match for as much people as possible (it's impossible to compute a match for everyone). It makes a graph where vertexes are users and edges are the grades

I simplify the problem by saying that if 2 people give a grade to each other, there is an edge between them with a weight of their respective grade average. But if A give a grade to B, but B doesnt, their is no edge between them and they can never match : this way, the graph is not oriented anymore

**I would like that, in average everybody be happy, but in the same time, I would like as few as possible of people that have no match.**

Being very deterministic, I made an algorithm that find ALL maximal matchings in a graph. I did that because I thought I could analyse all these maximal matchings and apply a value function that could look like :

```
V(Matching) = exp(|M| / max(|M|)) * sum(weight of all Edge in M)
```

That is to say, a matching is high-valued if its cardinal is close to the cardinal of the maximum matching, and if the sum of the grade between people is high. I put an exponential function to the ratio |M|/max|M| because I consider it's a big problem if M is lower that 0.8 (so the exp will be arranged to highly decrease V as |M|/max|M| reaches 0.8)

I would have take the matching where V(M) is maximal. Though, the big problem is that my function that computes all maximal matching takes a lot of time. For only 15 vertex and 20 edges, it takes almost 10 minutes...
Here is the algorithm (in Swift) :

```
import Foundation

struct Edge : CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "e(\(v1), \(v2))"
    }

    let v1:Int
    let v2:Int
    let w:Int?

    init(_ arrint:[Int])
    {
        v1 = arrint[0]
        v2 = arrint[1]
        w = nil
    }
    init(_ v1:Int, _ v2:Int)
    {
        self.v1 = v1
        self.v2 = v2
        w = nil
    }
    init(_ v1:Int, _ v2:Int, _ w:Int)
    {
        self.v1 = v1
        self.v2 = v2
        self.w  = w
    }
}


let mygraph:[Edge] =
[
    Edge([1, 2]),
    Edge([1, 5]),
    Edge([2, 5]),
    Edge([2, 3]),
    Edge([3, 4]),
    Edge([3, 6]),
    Edge([5, 6]),

    Edge([2,6]),
    Edge([4,1]),
    Edge([3,5]),
    Edge([4,2]),
    Edge([7,1]),
    Edge([7,2]),

    Edge([8,1]),
    Edge([9,8]),
    Edge([11,2]),
    Edge([11, 8]),
    Edge([12,13]),
    Edge([1,6]),
    Edge([4,7]),
    Edge([5,7]),
    Edge([3,5]),
    Edge([9,1]),
    Edge([10,11]),
    Edge([10,4]),
    Edge([10,2]),
    Edge([10,1]),
    Edge([10, 12]),


]

// remove all the edge and vertex "touching" the edges and vertex in "edgePath"
func reduce (graph:[Edge], edgePath:[Edge]) -> [Edge]
{

    var alreadyUsedV:[Int] = []

    for edge in edgePath
    {
        alreadyUsedV.append(edge.v1)
        alreadyUsedV.append(edge.v2)
    }


    return graph.filter({ edge in
        return alreadyUsedV.first(where:{ edge.v1 == $0 }) == nil && alreadyUsedV.first(where:{ edge.v2 == $0 }) == nil
    })

}


func findAllMaximalMatching(graph Gi:[Edge]) -> [[Edge]]
{

    var matchings:[[Edge]] = []

    var G = Gi // current graph (reduced at each depth)
    var M:[Edge] = [] // current matching being built
    var Cx:[Int] = [] // current path in the possibilities tree 
                      // eg : Cx[1] = 3 : for the depth 1, we are at the 3th edge 
    var d:Int = 0 // current depth

    var debug_it = 0


    while(true)
    {

        if(G.count == 0) // if there is no available edge in graph, it means we have a matching
        {
            if(M.count > 0) // security, if initial Graph is empty we cannot return an empty matching
            {
                matchings.append(M)
            }

            if(d == 0)
            {
                // depth = 0, we cannot decrement d, we have finished all the tree possibilities
                break
            }
            d = d - 1

            _ = M.popLast()
            G = reduce(graph: Gi, edgePath: M)

        }

        else
        {
            let indexForThisDepth = Cx.count > d ? Cx[d] + 1 : 0
            if(G.count < indexForThisDepth + 1)
            {
                // depth ended,

                _ = Cx.popLast()

                if( d == 0)
                {
                    break
                }

                d = d - 1
                _ = M.popLast()

                // reduce from initial graph to the decremented depth
                G = reduce(graph: Gi, edgePath: M)

            }
            else
            {
                // matching not finished to be built
                M.append( G[indexForThisDepth] )

                if(indexForThisDepth == 0)
                {
                    Cx.append(indexForThisDepth)
                }
                else
                {
                    Cx[d] = indexForThisDepth
                }

                d = d + 1
                G = reduce(graph: G, edgePath: M)
            }
        }

        debug_it += 1
    }


    print("matching counts : \(matchings.count)")
    print("iterations : \(debug_it)")

    return matchings

}


let m = findAllMaximalMatching(graph: mygraph)

// we have compute all the maximal matching, now we loop through all of them to find the one that has V(Mi) maximum
// ....
```

**Finally my question is : how can I optimize this algorithm to find all maximal matching and to compute my value function on them to find the best matching for my app in a polynomial time ?**

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something since the question is quite complicated, but why not simply use [maximum flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem#Maximum_cardinality_bipartite_matching), with every vertex appearing twice and the edges weights are the average grading if exists? It will return the maximal flow if configured correctly and runs polynomial time.

Comment: I don’t understand how my problem of finding matching is linked with the maximum flow problem can you explain a bit more ?